# How to convert to normal string

Tags: python

I have a string and want convert to normal string

```
import sys
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

text = '\u3010\U0001f469\U0001f3fb\u200d'
text.translate(non_bmp_map)#'【��\u200d'
```

How to view the last character correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `str.decode`

**Ex:**

```
text = '\u3010\U0001f469\U0001f3fb\u200d'
print text.decode('unicode-escape')            #python2.7
```

**Output:**

```
【
```

Comment: I am using Python 3. How to do it?

Comment: @Mike, visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299155/python-3-decoding-strings.

Comment: Before decoding the string, I need to encode it. But how to do it correctly? I tried `text.encode('latin-1').decode('Unicode_escape')`. An error appeared : `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(256)`